# Exit code from .cmd execution

Tags: python, batch-file

In one of our automation script below command get executed which call `installer.cmd` but it comes out after 4 hours as timed out and my main command status getting set as failed.
It would be great help if I get a solution for this issue

```
cd <build path>\Disk1 & start /wait "Upgrade Operation" install.cmd -i silent -DOPTIONS_FILE=\"<build path>\Disk1\upgrade.options\"
```

Content of install.cmd is as below,

```
:runcommand
set __COMMAND="%__SETUP_EXE%" %__COMMAND_LINE_ARGS%
set __COMMAND_LINE_ARGS=
set __SETUP_EXE=
if %__FROM_CONSOLE% EQU 1 (
  ECHO Info:Executing command - %__COMMAND%
  set __FROM_CONSOLE=
  %__COMMAND%
  ECHO Info:Execution of %__COMMAND% completed
) else (
  ECHO Info:Executing command - %__COMMAND%
  set __FROM_CONSOLE=
  start /wait "" %__COMMAND%
  ECHO Info:Execution of %__COMMAND% completed
)

:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::
:: END                                                                       ::
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::
:end
set __COMMAND_LINE_ARGS=
set __FROM_CONSOLE=
set __SETUP_EXE=
@if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" endlocal
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged as Python?

Comment: Using python code we are forming the command to be executed,so thought it will be helpfull to provide solution

Comment: Any solution for above query????